# Hundreds of "SaveToSessionResponseWrapper Skip invoking on" in logs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application using JPA backed domain objects; Redis is used for caching. The frontend is using Thymeleaf.

My controller retrieves the data super quick as I can see the logging lines for "Start" and "End" but when I pass the object model to the frontend it takes ages to load with the following lines showing in the logs when 'DEBUG' mode is on:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/person/{id}/edit")
public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
    logger.warn(">>> Start <<<");
    Person person = service.findViewObjectById(id);
    logger.warn(">>> End <<<"); 
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "admin/person/form";
}
```

`2018-04-18 10:31:02.132 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.133 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.133 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.133 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.133 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.134 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.134 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.134 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2018-04-18 10:31:02.134 DEBUG 15676 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on`

**Count: 8,807**

The classes in question are:[HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html) and [SaveToSessionResponseWrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html)

> A SecurityContextRepository implementation which stores the security context in the HttpSession between requests.

For what's worth my security config is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
}
```

**Using**: Java 8, Spring Boot (v1.3.1), Spring (4.2.4), Thymeleaf (2.1.4)

Comment: What version of spring session do you have? Does this apply? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3364#issuecomment-280035489

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik thanks; I had looked at that post but I am using a newer version of Spring. I've updated the desc to include the version.

Comment: Can you post your HTML page?  Or perhaps simplify it to isolate the issue?  May not be the culprit, but occasionally I see `th:each` loops or JS that causes things like this to happen.